# Set order as paid using Shopify Python API

Tags: python, shopify, shopify-api

I have orders that were placed with Shopify, but were paid with an external payment system. I am trying to mark them as paid using the Python API, but am getting a 406 response when saving the transaction. The private app in the store has  read and write set for Orders API

```
shop_url = "https://%s:%s@mystore.myshopify.com/admin/api/%s" % (API_KEY, PASSWORD, API_VERSION) 
shopify.ShopifyResource.set_site(shop_url)

shop = shopify.Shop.current();

order = shopify.Order.find_first(name="#20204512"); 
trans = shopify.Transaction.find_first(order_id=order.id); 
new_transaction = shopify.Transaction(); 
#new_transaction.currency = "CAD";
new_transaction.kind = "capture" 
#new_transaction.status = "paid" 
#new_transaction.gateway = "manual" 
new_transaction.amount = "10.00"; 
new_transaction.parent_id = trans.id;
new_transaction.save();
```

Comment: Are you sending this after creating the order or while creating the order?

Comment: @HymnZ After the order is created through checkout on Shopify website

Comment: In that case, the order is already being marked as paid. Do check the order payment status. Also, you only need to send `kind` and `amount` . Other fields are not required.

Comment: @HymnZ, The order I am testing it with has a status of "Payment pending". Do I still need to keep parent_id?

Comment: The api url you should be sending the data is `/admin/orders/order_id/transactions.json` and you only need to send `kind` and `amount` . Just check if this is what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Python API has an issue.
Add the following line before saving:

```
new_transaction._prefix_options ={"order_id" : order.id}
```

This will resolve the 406 error.